# API to check network connectivity for a location

Tags: api, location, connectivity, cellular-network

I would like to know if someone here is aware of any APIs for figuring out cellular connectivity at a given location (in coordinates). This is for offline processing of some location data.

- Any network is fine. (t-mobile, verizon etc)
- Any language is fine for me.
- Paid APIs are fine too.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution. https://opensignal.com/ maps various carriers, their signal strength and data rates through volunteers that install their apps on their phones. It is remarkable the amount of data they have collected.

They also have a developer portal at https://opensignal.3scale.net/ where you can register to get API keys. For some reason, the API documentation is not available on their website. It is still available on their [archived website](https://web.archive.org/web/20160105122324/http://developer.opensignal.com/networkrank/%20archived%20website). This describes the json format of the response.

As an example, the following python code fetches the json information:

```
import json
import urllib2
def get_network_stats(lat, lng, bounding_box_size):
    key = '<key>'
    url = 'http://api.opensignal.com/v2/networkstats.json?' + \
          'lat=' + str(lat) + '&lng=' + str(lng) + \
          '&distance=' + str(bounding_box_size) + \
          '&json_format=2&apikey=' + key
    return json.load(urllib2.urlopen(url))

response = get_network_stats(40.7128, 74.0059, 1)
```

`response` has the network statistics for a 1kmx1km bounding box around the given coordinates. It is the average of all the data collected, separated by the network providers.

Comment: API access gone now :(